Old horror movie, few stories in one movie?
Horror film that contained few, probably unrelated stories (I am not sure if it was 3 or 4 stories). I watched it around 1998, but it seemed to be pretty old back then. It wasn't Creepshow. Might have been an episode of Tales from the Crypt, but I tried to find it with no luck. I remember very little:

One story featured a scene, where near end a man got close to a woman sitting in a chair and she turned out to be a skeleton/deformed thing.
Last story started with a man arriving at strange town, where there was probably no one there (or hiding, ignoring him, can't remember) except for a girl, and she kept saying that he needs to leave before "elder" or something like that will come, but in the end he didn't manage to leave before that event and when I was about to find out what secret this town has, the tape ended and it didn't record.

It was many years ago and I still want to know what happened, please help!

What year did you see it? Or about what year? And are there any other details that you can give. Like how many stories were there?

Wasn't Creepshow?

I watched it around 1998, but it seemed to be pretty old back then. I am not sure if it was 3 or 4 stories so I won't help this way. The only thing that is really vivid for me is the last story that I wrote about. It wasn't creepshow. Might have been episode of Tales from the Crypt, but I tired to find it with no luck.

That's definitely not Creepshow (or Creepshow II). I've seen both more times than I'd like to admit.

Was it in color?

It could be The Monster Club (1981).
This is a portmanteau horror film consisting of 3 stories.
One story featured a scene, where near end a man got close to a woman sitting in a chair and she turned out to be a skeleton/deformed thing.
This could be interpreted as the end of the first story, The Shadmock
From the wikipedia synopsis:

Angela is caught robbing the Shadmock's safe, and screams that she
  could never love him. Heartbroken, the Shadmock whistles and destroys
  Angela's face. Upon seeing her, her boyfriend is driven insane and
  locked away in an asylum.

Last story started with a man arriving at strange town, where there was probably no one there (or hiding, ignoring him, can't remember) except for a girl, and she kept saying that he needs to leave before "elder" or something like that will come, but in the end he didn't manage to leave before that event and when I was about to find out what secret this town has, the tape ended and it didn't record.
This is a good match for the third story, The Ghouls
Here's a bit of the plot from the wiki with spoilery info removed:

A movie director scouting locations for his next film pays a horrifying visit to an isolated, decrepit village, Loughville near Hillington, Norfolk, where the sinister residents refuse to let him leave. He discovers to his horror that the village is inhabited by species of man-eating ghouls who unearth graves for food and clothes. And now there are no more graves to plunder and the ghouls are hungry for flesh. While imprisoned by the ghouls, he meets Luna. Luna advises him to hide in the church, as ghouls cannot cross holy ground. The director with the aid of Luna attempts to escape.

I remember a couple more facts not mentioned here:

The village is surrounded by a veil of mist. 
There is mention of
village "elders" who will come later.


Is it Freaky Fairytales, Deadtime Stories?




You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
