# Weird British movie with zombie creatures in a fog

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

Driving me nuts for years, but I watched a movie probably 25 years ago that was really weird.  All I remember is:

- I'm pretty sure it was British or some other European film.
- There was a town that was on the other side of a bridge that was cloaked in a fog and zombie like creatures lived there.
- There was a scene where an older couple lived in a house and the older woman was brushing her teeth and they started falling out, and the older man told her that her breath smelled like death and she started screaming and crying.
- At one point there was a person or two people that ran out of the bridge and the zombie creatures things were throwing crab apples, or rocks or something at him.
- I'm pretty sure the final scene had the person running down to a road, and a person passing by stopped and picked him up.  He was trying to escape, but the car took him back over the bridge into the foggy town and the ending scene just showed the zombie like people clawing at the car eerily.

Answer (score 4):

The last 2 points fit in with the third story of [*The Monster Club* (1981)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081178/).
This is a portmanteau horror film consisting of 3 stories.

(see this question: [Old horror movie, few stories in one movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38852/old-horror-movie-few-stories-in-one-movie/43410))

The third story is *The Ghouls*
From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monster_Club) synopsis with spoilery info removed:

> A movie director scouting locations for his next film pays a horrifying visit to an isolated, decrepit village, Loughville near Hillington, Norfolk, where the sinister residents refuse to let him leave. He discovers to his horror that the village is inhabited by species of man-eating ghouls who unearth graves for food and clothes. And now there are no more graves to plunder and the ghouls are hungry for flesh. While imprisoned by the ghouls, he meets Luna. Luna advises him to hide in the church, as ghouls cannot cross holy ground. The director with the aid of Luna attempts to escape.

I remember a couple more facts not mentioned here:

1. The village is surrounded by a veil of mist.
2. There is mention of
   village "elders" who will come later.

At the end...

> At the end, the main guy stops a police car which drives back to the
>  village. The police turn out to be the "elders".

Edit: Found a video: